# php adding float number gives wrong result

Tags: php, floating-point

I am getting wrong result while adding float numbers, pls tell me how you programmer are escaping from this

Code:

```
 $tot = 0;
    $ans = (float)101;
    for($i=1; $i<= 10; $i++){
        $tot = $tot + 10.1;
    }
    var_dump($tot);
    var_dump($ans);
    if($tot == $ans){
        echo '<br />Both are equal ';
    }
    else{
        echo '<br />Both are not equal ';
    }
```

Result:

float 101

float 101

**Both are not equal**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is inherited from `C` language.

There will be a small difference while comparing floating values,

See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php), ans [this](http://www.scribd.com/doc/5836/What-Every-Computer-Scientist-Should-Know-About-Floating-Point-Arithmetic)

try this,

```
if (abs(($tot-$ans)/$tot) < 0.00001) {
    echo '<br />Both are equal ';
}
else{
    echo '<br />Both are not equal ';
}
```

Comment: number_format($tot, 5) is also a solution at least for this case

Comment: But shud should understand that floating values should not be compared like this.

Comment: you mean, compare like number_format($tot, 5) ?

Comment: No, this is correct, while comparing the floating values, the difference will be very minimal, so ur correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try with '==='
, '==' compares the variable references and '===' compares the value

```
if($tot === $ans){
    echo '<br />Both are equal ';
}
else{
    echo '<br />Both are not equal ';
}
```

Comment: No change if I am changing the operator